# SSIS Web Service Task: Dynamically setting WSDLFile

Tags: web-services, configuration, ssis

Is there any way to dynamically set the WSDLFile (the one on the Web Service Task Editor) for a SSIS service, so that the filepath is not hardcoded on the package? We want to be able to change this value the way you change values with .config files, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can set the WSDLFile property via an Expression.  Select the task, then properties, then Expressions and select WSDLFile from the drop down.  You can then populate it from a variable which you can set in the config file.  Alternatively, you can set the WSDLFile directly from a Package Configuration.

Comment: Thanks! I had already tried to do it via Package configuration but I didnt find the wsdlfile option, but now that you said so i double checked and i found it at the very bottom of the options ( I was looking at connection manager, and its under executables). I wasn't able to do it the other way though, i clicked Expressions on properties but I don't get the WSDLFile option :/. Im using VS2005